# How to show the appointment page from a form region in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have a very simple outlook form region. It is configured as a separate item, and, it is set to appear whenever a we try to compose a new appointment item. (Meeting request).

[image]

Once I click the button above, it should populate the sender and go back to the main appointment page. The code to do that is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item.RequiredAttendees = "John.Doe@contoso.com";
        var exp = item.Application.ActiveInspector();
        if (exp == null) Debug.Print("NULL");
        else exp.ShowFormPage("Appointment");
    }
```

But this doesn't do anything. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SetCurrentFormPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868251.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Inspector class to display the specified form page or form region in the inspector.

As a workaround you may try to call the Appointment button programmatically. Use the [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx) method of the CommandBars class to execute the control identified by the idMso parameter. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) for the actual idMso values.